# R: How to take keys in nested lists and turn them into columns of a dataframe with the corresponding key values as row values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named raw_data pulled from a JSON file in the first screenshot. Every column in raw_data is one list containing all the numeric or string values I need, and by doing `unnest` I could get them all out of the list with no issues.

But my problem is with the column "teams" in the 2nd screenshot provided(2nd screenshot is of one row value in the column "teams"). Because raw_data[[10]][[13]][[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N29fd.png)]][[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N29fd.png)]] represents player 1 and raw_data[[10]][[13]][[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N29fd.png)][[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N29fd.png)]] represents player 2, I want them all to be seperate columns in one data frame, like "profile_id_p1" and "profile_id_p2", "result_p1" and "result_p2" and so on... By doing unnest it gets rid of player 2's list completely.

How could I make a dataframe with all columns of raw_data and separate player-1 and player-2 columns out of the sublist elements in "teams"? I also don't want any column to be a list.

[image: raw_data image]
[image: teams column in data frame]

(edit) SOLVED:

```
teams = raw_data$teams

player_1_list <- c()
player_2_list <- c()

#loop through teams and append index[1] into player_1_list and index[2] into player_2_list
for (player in teams){
  player_1_list <- append(player_1_list, player[1])
  player_2_list <- append(player_2_list, player[2])
}

#get rid of one layer of lists to get a list of dictionary(key,value)
p1_dic = unlist(player_1_list, recursive = FALSE)

p2_dic = unlist(player_2_list, recursive = FALSE)

#use rbindlist to turn the list of dictionaries into dataframes for p1 and p2
p1_df = rbindlist(p1_dic)

p2_df = rbindlist(p2_dic)
```

I made an empty vector for p1 and p2, used a for-loop to get p1 and p2's keys and values into their respective vectors.
Then got rid of a layer of nested list so now both player has their own list of keys and values.
Then `rbindlist` into dfs, rename the columns, combine them into the original dataframe.

This is not the most efficient way to do it but it worked, if anyone has a faster solution please feel free to answer, Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: You may need to use `unnest_wider() |> unnest()` or `unnest_longer() |> unnest() |> pivot_wider()`. Beyond that, we would need to see sample data, eg the result of `dput(head(raw_data))`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring from the subset of the list that it looks something like this:

```r
L <- list( list(list(profile_id=1, result="A", civ="otto")), list(list(profile_id=2, result="B", civ="roman"), list(profile_id=3, result="C", civ="greco")) )
str(L)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ profile_id: num 1
#   .. ..$ result    : chr "A"
#   .. ..$ civ       : chr "otto"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ profile_id: num 2
#   .. ..$ result    : chr "B"
#   .. ..$ civ       : chr "roman"
#   ..$ :List of 3
#   .. ..$ profile_id: num 3
#   .. ..$ result    : chr "C"
#   .. ..$ civ       : chr "greco"
```

I took some liberty with having more than one element in a 1-deep list, but ... if that doesn't happen, then these may still work.

### Option #1

The premise is that we are going to use `[[`-indexing with vectors (not as common a sighting), where the n-th element of the vector goes to the n-th level of the nested list.

For example,

```r
L[[c(2,1,3)]]
# [1] "roman"
```

With the data as you've shown it, it looks as if the 3rd level are named-lists which means they can be converted to frames directly, so we know need to go 2-levels deep in our indexing.

```r
len1 <- seq_along(L)
len2 <- lapply(L, seq_along)
cbind(rep(len1, times = lengths(len2)), unlist(len2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    1
# [3,]    2    2
```

We're going to take each row of that matrix and use it to call `L[[.]]`. With that, we should get simpler list of named elements, which we can convert to frames, and then combine into a single frame.

```r
cbind(rep(len1, times = lengths(len2)), unlist(len2)) |>
  asplit(1) |>
  lapply(function(i) as.data.frame(L[[i]])) |>
  do.call(rbind, args=_)
#   profile_id result   civ
# 1          1      A  otto
# 2          2      B roman
# 3          3      C greco
```

Note that the use of `base::rbind.data.frame` strictly requires that all columns be the same class, same name, and in the same order. If you want a little more flexibility with that requirement, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows(.)` or `data.table::rbindlist(., use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`, as in

```r
cbind(rep(len1, times = lengths(len2)), unlist(len2)) |>
  asplit(1) |>
  lapply(function(i) as.data.frame(L[[i]])) |>
  bind_rows()
```

It's not clear in your original question if your 3-deep frames are perhaps nested more in the real list. For that, you might need an "Inception" approach where you create the matrix (as we did) with more columns. (This also assumes that the depth of the frame-like lists are consistent.)

---

### Option #2

A recursive function *might* work for you.

```r
fun <- function(lst) {
  if (!is.null(names(lst)) && !any(sapply(lst, is.list))) return(as.data.frame(lst))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, fun))
}
fun(L)
#   profile_id result   civ
# 1          1      A  otto
# 2          2      B roman
# 3          3      C greco
```

Again, `do.call(rbind, .)` vs `bind_rows(.)` and such.

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
I thought by doing the fill = TRUE it would fill in values so that the rows and columns do match, but all of the options return this error.

Comment: I don't know, there are plenty of ways that could happen. Please share sample data that shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `L` provided by @r2evans, you could also do:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unlist(L, FALSE), data.frame))

  profile_id result   civ
1          1      A  otto
2          2      B roman
3          3      C greco
```

---

```
array2DF(array(unlist(L, FALSE), 3))[-1] # You will have to unlist the columns
  profile_id result   civ
1          1      A  otto
2          2      B roman
3          3      C greco
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(L, ~unnest(as_tibble(transpose(.x)), everything()))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  profile_id result civ  
       <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
1          1 A      otto 
2          2 B      roman
3          3 C      greco
```

---

```
library(jsonlite)

bind_rows(fromJSON(toJSON(L)))

  profile_id result   civ
1          1      A  otto
2          2      B roman
3          3      C greco
```

And many more:

Data:

```
L <- list( list(list(profile_id=1, result="A", civ="otto")), list(list(profile_id=2, result="B", civ="roman"), list(profile_id=3, result="C", civ="greco")) )
```